# Why transaction gas used increased after London hardfork?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am developing a smart contract and I recently updated Hardhat to 2.6.x, which has london hardfork as default network settings. My issue is that gas used by my transaction increased by more than 50% in most cases. When I switch back to berlin hardfork, the cost is "correct" again.

Can somebody explain me why? Is there some updated opcode gas cost list? Or did gas cost for storing / loading values from storage increased? I am failing in finding the source of the increase.

I read EIP-1559, but there is no much information about opcode updates, just gas price and model of a base fee burning, which should not increase transaction gas usage imo.

I use ethers and property gasUsed on transaction receipt to get used gas.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529) is the reason of the increase. EIP-3529 is reducing gas refunds and for one NFT transfers its ~20k gas increase because while transferring NFT you set storage of previous owner and (in some cases) his balance to 0, which are refunded less after london hardfork. Unfortunate.